# Exclude certain indices from a KFold split in Python SKlearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am using SKlearn KFold as follows:

```
        kf = KFold(10000, n_folds=5, shuffle=True, random_state=88)
```

However, I want to exclude certain indices from the training folds (only). How can this be achieved? Thanks.

I wonder if this can be achieved by using sklearn.cross_validation.PredefinedSplit?

---

Update: The KFold instance will be used with XGBoost for the **folds** parameter of xgb.cv. The Python API [here](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) states that folds should be "a KFold or StratifiedKFold instance".

However, I will try generating the KFolds as above, iterating over the train fold indices, modifying them, and then defining a custom_cv by hand like this:

```
custom_cv = zip(train_indices, test_indices)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "return them to the KFold object"? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The KFold will be given to XGBoost for xgb.cv. I need to remove certain indices from the training folds before passing the KFold instance to xgb.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by "return them to the KFold object."

Comment: Using KFold, I split my training data into train and valid. I am going to pass the KFold instance to XGBoost, which will use it during its cross validation. However, before I do that, I want to exclude some specific indices from the training data only (not the valid data). An alternative way to do it is to use fpreproc, but it involves modifying a DMatrix object. Hope that clarifies. If there is a better way to exclude certain indices from the KFold split, please let me know. I will modify the question to clarify.

Comment: I'm not familiar with XGBoost, but if you do something like `kf_list = list(kf)` it will return a list of tuples which is will be iterable in the same way as the KFold object and you can remove the indices you want from the tuples in the list.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I remove indices from kf_list in that manner, will that also change the KFold instance?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to remove indices from the training set, but it is ok if they are in the testing set, then this approach will work:

```
kf_list = list(kf)
```

This will return a list of tuples that can be iterated over in the same way as the KFold instance. You can then simply modify the indices as you see fit, and your KFold instance will stay untouched. You can think of a KFold object as an array of integers, representing the indices, and methods that let you generate the folds on the fly.

Here's the source code, which is pretty straightforward, for the meaty part of how the iterator protocol is implemented :

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/cross_validation.py#L254

```
def _iter_test_indices(self):
    n = self.n
    n_folds = self.n_folds
    fold_sizes = (n // n_folds) * np.ones(n_folds, dtype=np.int)
    fold_sizes[:n % n_folds] += 1
    current = 0
    for fold_size in fold_sizes:
        start, stop = current, current + fold_size
        yield self.idxs[start:stop]
        current = stop
```

Comment: Does modifying the kf_list also modify the KFold instance though? If list() just creates a copy, and the KFold instance remains unchanged, the changes will not be passed on to xgb.  Thanks.

Comment: No, it doesn't. But why do you ask?

Comment: As I said, I will be passing the KFold instance to XGBoost. Those folds will then be used in cross validation. If the KFold instance remains unchanged, it doesn't help. I need to exclude the specific indices from the cross validation.

Comment: Aha. Sorry, now I see. So,  it *has* to be an instance of KFold?

Comment: the question is clearly asking how this special split can be achieved with KFold, and the answer is simply providing a manual solution that doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: @AshkanKazemi in my defense, if you look at the original question prior to the edits, that wasn't clear. If you really needed to do this by passing a KFold instance, you could use some wrapper object, or less robustly, inherit and override these non-public methods that are used to implement the iterator.

Comment: fair enough. i'd be happy to upvote your answer if you edit it to answer the current question. i did my own search through sklearn docs and found PredefinedSplit to work in such cases.